# Transposing the values of d3.nest result

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects which looks like this

```
[{center_name:"AXCG", 1_to_2years:34, 3_to_4years:12, 5_to_6years:45},
 {center_name:"BDGT", 1_to_2years:67, 3_to_4years:23, 5_to_6years:45}]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
  {"key":"AXCG","values":[
    {"interval":'1_to_2years',"value":34},
    {"interval":'3_to_4years',"value":12},
    {"interval":'5_to_6years',"value":45},
  ]},
  {"key":"BDGT","values":[
    {"interval":'1_to_2years',"value":34},
    {"interval":'3_to_4years',"value":12},
    {"interval":'5_to_6years',"value":45},
  ]}]
```

After using d3.nest, I could get center_names as keys how do I transpose the values

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.center_name; })
.entries(output_array);
```

Comment: Is your array of objects a single object that contain a mixed bag of string and numbers? or are there a separate array for center_name and an other one for AXCG, etc?

Comment: array of objects where a single objects look like{center_name: "AXCG",1_to_2years:34, 3_to_4years:12, 5_to_6years:45}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your old array into the new structure in various ways. Here is one of them:

```js
var data = [
     {center_name:"AXCG", 
      "1_to_2years":34, 
      "3_to_4years":12, 
      "5_to_6years":45},
    {center_name:"BDGT", 
      "1_to_2years":67, 
      "3_to_4years":23, 
      "5_to_6years":45}
      ];

var new_data = [];       //start with an empty array

//loop through original data item-by-item
data.forEach(function(d){
  var obj = {};                //prepare an empty object
  obj.key = d.center_name;     
  obj.values = [];             // prepare internal empty array
  
  //we need the key values from the object
  Object.keys(d).forEach(function(key){
    // but only keys that contain the word (year)...
    if(key.indexOf("years")>-1){
      //setting up the new data structure
      obj.values.push({interval:key,value:d[key]});
    }
  });
  // finally, pushing the object to the new array
  new_data.push(obj);
});

  console.log(new_data);
```